While trying to use docker to run my project based on pythonnet the c# runtime is not found
screenshot
I keep getting this error:
RuntimeError: Failed to create a default .NET runtime, which would
                    have been "mono" on this system. Either install a
                    compatible runtime or configure it explicitly via
                    `set_runtime` or the `PYTHONNET_*` environment variables
                    (see set_runtime_from_env).

I have my docker file i don't have any runtime specified. Is that the issue?
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as base

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files.
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Keeps Python from buffering stdout and stderr to avoid situations where
# the application crashes without emitting any logs due to buffering.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

# Create a non-privileged user that the app will run under.
# See https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-user-best-practices/
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser

# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.cache/pip to speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage a bind mount to requirements.txt to avoid having to copy them into
# into this layer.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Switch to the non-privileged user to run the application.
USER appuser

# Copy the source code into the container.
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 5491

# Run the application.
CMD python src/main.py

I tried to use docker to run my project using pythonnet. So i can use the sterling trader api.

You need to install at the bare minimum a .NET runtime in your container. That's what the error message is telling you, it's even suggesting the mono runtime.
